# Home Screen Widget focusable(to select it with D-Pad). Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to make my Homescreen App Widget focusable. So far I've set **focusable** and **clickable**="true" in the root Layout of the Widget but with no successs. I wasn't able to find on the internet a working example on how to make the widget focusable. I'm starting to wonder whether is it possible to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by focusable? You need to click on widget button and get action to application ?

Comment: I mean focusable when working with D-Pad, I cannot select it with the D-Pad, the widget acts as it was invisible in the home screen